# Are all closed subgroups of $GL_n ( \mathbb{R})$ defined by an invariant(more precisely stable) cone in the tensor algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups

Many classical Lie subgroups of $GL_n (\mathbb{R}) $ are defined by a tensor(or tensors) it leaves invariant, such as the orthogonal group, special linear group, symplectic group etc. Of course there is the connected component $ GL_n( \mathbb{R})_0$ of $GL_n( \mathbb{R})$, which leaves invariant(or acts stably on, to be more precise) a cone of tensors, namely the cone of positive volume forms. I'm guessing that after complexification the cone behaviour wouldn't exist. My question is, do the invariant tensors determine the subgroup? Knowing this for complex Lie subgroups would be nice too, which I would hope to have a cleaner explanation.

Comment: There is an easy statement of this form if you replace "closed" with "Zariski-closed." Then there is a more interesting statement of this form for compact subgroups. This should be related to Tannaka-Krein (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tannaka%E2%80%93Krein_duality) and Doplicher-Roberts (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Doplicher-Roberts+reconstruction+theorem) but I'm not sure what the exact statements end up looking like.